# Restrict $x$ in an equation, but keeping only one equation

Tags: functions

How do you put restrictions on the $x$ in an equation without writing more than one equation? This is a two part question:

1. How to take out a section of the graph of an equation?
2. How to take out everything but a section of the graph of an equation?

For example, to take out $x$ from $-1$ to $1$ in $y=|x|$, you can change the equation to $$y=|x|\times\dfrac{\sqrt{|x|-1}}{\sqrt{|x|-1}}$$

I need to take a function, say $f(x)$, and restrict it to $1 < x < 4$.

Comment: which limit do you mean?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner for example, we have $|x|$ and we want to graph only when $|x|>=4$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the task is to modify a function's formula so that the new natural domain constrains the graph to what we desire.

Comment: @Adayah that is correct

Comment: It will depend on what kind of restriction you need. You want to exclude one number, exclude an interval, limit to an interval? Is the interval bounded? It's hard to give an all-encompassing answer. Do you want the equation to be undefined otherwise, or zero otherwise?

Comment: I need to take a function, say f(x), and limit x to 1<x<4

Comment: @IonLee This is called "restricting" and not limiting. I have edited your question to hopefully make your intent clear; please check to make sure it's what you intended. I also added your comment to the question.

Comment: @GFauxPas my bad. Yes the question is much more clear now. Thanks!

Comment: Oops! I had an answer posted here, then promptly realized I made a rookie mistake...

Comment: @SeanHenderson I didn't notice a mistake?

Comment: @gfauxpas - You know...I think you're right. I just second-guessed myself too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. If you want to restrict the domain to $1 < x < 4$, simply multiply and divide by square root which would imply the two separate restrictions $x>1$ and $x<4$. In this case. Those would be $\sqrt{x-1}$ and $\sqrt{4-x}$. Put it all together and you have

> $f(x)_{restricted} = f(x) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{4-x}}$.

The process for eliminating everything *but* a certain region is similar.

Comment: I had initially deleted this answer thinking it actually didn't work, but of course the restrictions created by these square roots indicate regions which ARE valid, not regions which AREN'T. I thought for a second I had accidentally eliminated all x values greater than one and all x values less than four and, thus, ALL x values. That, clearly, was not the case.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\frac{\ln x}{\ln x}$ is the identity on $(0,\infty)$ and the function $\frac{1+\sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}$ is the identity on $[0,\infty)$. These can be used to "retain" intervals with one endpoint at infinity. For example to restrict to $[a,b)$ we multiply by $\frac{1+\sqrt{x-a}}{1+\sqrt{x-a}} \cdot \frac{\ln b-x}{\ln b-x}$.

For more complicated unions of intervals, you can use polynomial equations with $p(x) \ge 0 \Rightarrow x\in \bar \Omega$ where $\Omega$ is your desired domain and then multiply by $\frac{\ln p(x)}{\ln p(x)}$ or $\frac{1+\sqrt{p(x)}}{1+\sqrt {p(x)}}$ depending on whether you want to include the endpoints or not. If these are also mixed, you can exclude a single point by using $\frac{\ln |x-a|}{\ln |x-a|}$ as a factor.

Restriction to $(1,4)$ as you ask, can be done with the $\ln$-template:
$$f|_{(1,4)}(x) = f(x) \cdot \frac{\ln(x-1)}{\ln(x-1)} \cdot \frac{\ln(4-x)}{\ln(4-x)}$$

Or, more elegantly, $f(x) \cdot \frac{\ln(\frac32 - |\frac52-x|)}{\ln(\frac32-|\frac52 - x|)}$ where $\frac52 = \frac12(1+4)$ and $\frac32 = \frac12(4-1)$ are the midpoint and radius of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to introduce something like the characteristic function,the Kronecker delta function, or an Iverson bracket, or the heaviside step function. You can find information on those on wikipedia or proofwiki.org. They allow you to assign a variable that takes on $1$ under some condition and $0$ otherwise. Then your function won't be undefined otherwise, it will be zero, but in practical applications that's generally just fine, if not better.

Let's say you don't want to do that, for some reason.

For a restriction to an unbounded interval, start with a function that has an easy to manipulate domain. I'll use $\ln$, but $\sqrt{\phantom{x}}$ works just as well.

$$\ln x : x > 0$$

You can easily switch the direction of this by a minus sign:

$$\ln (-x) : -x > 0$$

and we have $-x > 0 \iff x < 0$

Let's say I want to limit my function to $x < -2$. Then I can multiply by:

$$\frac{\ln (-x-2)}{\ln (-x-2)} = 1: -x - 2 > 0$$

and we have $-x - 2 > 0 \iff x < -2$

You can do this more than once. Let's say I want to limit the function to $-10 < x < -2$. Then we can combine the restrictions of $x > -10$ and $x < -2$:

> $$\frac{\ln (-x-2)}{\ln (-x-2)} \frac{\ln (x+10)}{\ln (x+10)} = 1: -x - 2 > 0,x+10 > 0$$

and we have $x < -2 \text{ and } x> -10$.

Offhand, I can't think of a way to exclude the endpoints in the restriction, but if I think of one I'll update this answer.

Edit: AlexR has an excellent way to exclude the endpoints in the restriction.